# How to get pan-tilt servos quiet forever after first adjustments

Tags: servo

I have a camera mounted in an Adafruit pan-tilt mini kit with 2 servos (SG92R).
Installed python-smbus and i2c-tools.
From raspi-config I enabled `5 Interfacing options` `P5 I2C`.
Also installed Adafruit_Python_PCA9685.
Executing a python script I position the camera.

I only use pan-tilt to fine tune the camera position just at startup for timelapse.
I found that despite I added a @reboot line in crontab to run that script with the same two parameters (horizontal and vertical servo positions) I used the first time, just in case of restart after power failure or manual reboot, the position of the camera is slightly different than the original one.

I tried disabling I2C interface option but the result is far away the original position of the camera.

Then only way I guess I can accomplish that is to disconnect the power of the pan-tilt controller (Adafruit) after getting the best position but this could be a mess for me.

Is there another way to get servos quiet in case of reboot?

Comment: maybe a disk brake that is clamped by a spring and released by another servo

Comment: Sounds good but tricky. No idea how to accomplish that.

Comment: something like this, but the servo would pull the brake open 
 ... https://youtu.be/mOGItAg7tmY?t=39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this issue thanks to Adafruit techs.
I added a non-latching relay to control the power output from the RPi to the servo controller PCA9685.
For example GPIO6 is set to INPUT by default so when I need to move the servos I change the state to OUTPUT and the servos get power.
After adjustments are made I turn the state to INPUT to cut the power.
As said, after reboot, servos don't get power to move because I choose a GPIO pin with an INPUT state (LOW/OFF).
Here's the wiring schema I used [image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need more expensive servos?  They are more likely to go to the same position when given the same commands (pulse widths).

Also remember that servos will only maintain a position against a force if they are powered and are continually receiving the same commands (pulse width).

Comment: This is my kit: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-videos/1024x768/1967-02.mp4  https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/1200x900/1967-01.jpg  I understand what you say about more reliable servos but I also would need the assembly structure. I found one larger (metal) compatible with these servos: MG995 or HS322,HS422,Hitec,Parallax,Futaba, etc 40×20×36mm. I don't know if they would serve my needs. They also must be compatible with my PCA9685 16-Channel PWM Servo Motor Driver I2C Module. I remember I tried a couple of EMAX ES08MD servos but they didn't work

Comment: @dstonek Perhaps there is simply too much slack in the system to get repeatable results.  I think the astronomy guys would probably use stepper motors on their mounts for a variety of reasons.  You may need to find a more specialized site to ensure that the proper eyes see your problem and can offer a good solution.

Comment: Yesterday I've replicated this question at https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=131435&p=653268#p653268 and I got interesting answers.